How to adapt a 1D CNN residual network to handle a different input frequency for time series data?
I have found a model to classify sleep stages based on an ECG signal in a paper and their model is publicly available on Github. Their model is designed to take an input window of 270 seconds at 200 Hz. This results in an input size of (1,54000) and that works fine and dandy. I want to try and look at its performance when you downsample the signal to 64 Hz. This results in a input window of 64*270 = (1,17280). I have two questions.

Is it appropriate to only change the input without touching the kernel size or should that also be decreased?

How do I change their model to be able to run with 64 Hz?


This is the sample code to run their model:
import torch as th
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, Lin, Lout, filter_len, dropout, subsampling, momentum, maxpool_padding=0):
        assert filter_len%2==1
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()
        self.Lin = Lin
        self.Lout = Lout
        self.filter_len = filter_len
        self.dropout = dropout
        self.subsampling = subsampling
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.maxpool_padding = maxpool_padding

        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.Lin, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(self.dropout)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(self.Lin, self.Lin, self.filter_len, stride=self.subsampling, padding=self.filter_len//2, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.Lin, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(self.dropout)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(self.Lin, self.Lout, self.filter_len, stride=1, padding=self.filter_len//2, bias=False)
        #self.bn3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.Lout, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        if self.Lin==self.Lout and self.subsampling>1:
            self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(self.subsampling, padding=self.maxpool_padding)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.Lin==self.Lout:
            res = x
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        if self.Lin==self.Lout:
            if self.subsampling>1:
                x = x+self.maxpool(res)
            else:
                x = x+res
        #x = self.bn3(x)
        return x


class ECGSleepNet(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, to_combine=False,nb_classes = 5,n_timestep = 54000):#, filter_len):
        super(ECGSleepNet, self).__init__()
        self.filter_len = 17#33
        self.filter_num = 64#16
        self.padding = self.filter_len//2
        self.dropout = 0.5
        self.momentum = 0.1
        self.subsampling = 4
        self.n_channel = 1
        self.n_timestep = n_timestep#54000#//2
        #self.n_output = 5
        self.n_output = nb_classes
        self.to_combine = to_combine

        # input convolutional block
        # 1 x 54000
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, self.filter_num, self.filter_len, stride=1, padding=self.padding, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.filter_num, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()

        # 64 x 54000
        self.conv2_1 = nn.Conv1d(self.filter_num, self.filter_num, self.filter_len, stride=self.subsampling, padding=self.padding, bias=False)
        self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.filter_num, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(self.dropout)
        self.conv2_2 = nn.Conv1d(self.filter_num, self.filter_num, self.filter_len, stride=1, padding=self.padding, bias=False)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool1d(self.subsampling)
        #self.bn_input = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.filter_num, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)

        # 64 x 13500
        self.resblock1 = ResBlock(self.filter_num, self.filter_num, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)
        self.resblock2 = ResBlock(self.filter_num, self.filter_num, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum)
        self.resblock3 = ResBlock(self.filter_num, self.filter_num*2, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)
        self.resblock4 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*2, self.filter_num*2, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum, maxpool_padding=1)

        # 128 x 844
        self.resblock5 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*2, self.filter_num*2, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)
        self.resblock6 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*2, self.filter_num*2, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum)
        self.resblock7 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*2, self.filter_num*3, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)                
        self.resblock8 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*3, self.filter_num*3, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum, maxpool_padding=1)

        # 192 x 53
        self.resblock9 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*3, self.filter_num*3, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)
        self.resblock10 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*3, self.filter_num*3, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum, maxpool_padding=2)
        self.resblock11 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*3, self.filter_num*4, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)
        self.resblock12 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*4, self.filter_num*4, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, self.subsampling, self.momentum, maxpool_padding=2)

        # 256 x 4
        self.resblock13 = ResBlock(self.filter_num*4, self.filter_num*5, self.filter_len,
                self.dropout, 1, self.momentum)

        # 320 x 4
        self.bn_output = nn.BatchNorm1d(self.filter_num*5, momentum=self.momentum, affine=True)
        self.relu_output = nn.ReLU()

        #if not self.to_combine:
        dummy = self._forward(Variable(th.ones(1,self.n_channel, self.n_timestep)))
        self.fc_output = nn.Linear(dummy.size(1), self.n_output)

    def _forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.bn1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)

        res = x
        x = self.conv2_1(x)
        x = self.bn2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x)
        x = self.conv2_2(x)
        x = x+self.maxpool2(res)

        #x = self.bn_input(x)
        x = self.resblock1(x)
        x = self.resblock2(x)
        x = self.resblock3(x)
        x = self.resblock4(x)
        x = self.resblock5(x)
        x = self.resblock6(x)
        x = self.resblock7(x)
        x = self.resblock8(x)
        if hasattr(self, 'to_combine') and self.to_combine:
            return x
        x = self.resblock9(x)
        x = self.resblock10(x)
        x = self.resblock11(x)
        x = self.resblock12(x)
        x = self.resblock13(x)

        x = self.bn_output(x)
        x = self.relu_output(x)

        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        return x

    def forward(self, x):
        h = self._forward(x)
        if not hasattr(self, 'to_combine') or not self.to_combine:
            x = self.fc_output(h)

        return x, h

    def load_param(self, model_path):
        model = th.load(model_path)
        if type(model)==nn.DataParallel and hasattr(model, 'module'):
            model = model.module
        if hasattr(model, 'state_dict'):
            model = model.state_dict()
        self.load_state_dict(model)

    def fix_param(self):
        for param in self.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = False

    def unfix_param(self):
        for param in self.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True

    def init(self, method='orth'):
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Hz200_input = th.rand(1,1,54000)
    Hz64_input = th.rand(1,1,64*270)
    ECGPaper = ECGSleepNet(nb_classes = 5)
    output = ECGPaper(Hz200_input)
    output = ECGPaper(Hz64_input)

This works fine for the 200 Hz input but at the 64 Hz input it gives an error:
in forward
    x = x+self.maxpool(res)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (68) must match the size of tensor b (67) at non-singleton dimension 2

This happens in the "x = self.resblock6(x)" 6th resblock layer. Obviously the size of the layers change as the input size changes but how do I accommodate for that in an appropriate way? When printing out the sizes of the resblocks this is the result for the first six layers with 200 Hz and with 64 Hz:
output = ECGPaper(Hz200_input)
Output after resblock1: torch.Size([1, 64, 13500])
Output after resblock2: torch.Size([1, 64, 3375])
Output after resblock3: torch.Size([1, 128, 3375])
Output after resblock4: torch.Size([1, 128, 844])
Output after resblock5: torch.Size([1, 128, 844])
Output after resblock6: torch.Size([1, 128, 211])
Output after resblock7: torch.Size([1, 192, 211])
Output after resblock8: torch.Size([1, 192, 53])

output = ECGPaper(Hz64_input)
Output after resblock1: torch.Size([1, 64, 4320])
Output after resblock2: torch.Size([1, 64, 1080])
Output after resblock3: torch.Size([1, 128, 1080])
Output after resblock4: torch.Size([1, 128, 270])
Output after resblock5: torch.Size([1, 128, 270])

